# One different Folder per Line

Tags: sorting, powershell, permissions, directory, exchange-server

Im actually listing the folder Permissions of some Exhange Mailboxes with the following exchange command:

```
get-mailboxfolder -recurse | get-mailboxfolderpermissions | ft
```

Now the Output looks like this:

```
RunspaceId                    FolderName                    User                          AccessRights                  Identity                                            IsValid
----------                    ----------                    ----                          ------------                  --------                                            -------
0a6a00b7-859a-4297-b03f-41... Top of Information Store      Default                       {None}                        Default                                                True
0a6a00b7-859a-4297-b03f-41... Top of Information Store      Anonymous                     {None}                        Anonymous                                              True
0a6a00b7-859a-4297-b03f-41... Calendar                      Default                       {AvailabilityOnly}            Default                                                True
0a6a00b7-859a-4297-b03f-41... Calendar                      Anonymous                     {None}                        Anonymous                                              True
0a6a00b7-859a-4297-b03f-41... Contacts                      Default                       {None}                        Default                                                True
0a6a00b7-859a-4297-b03f-41... Contacts                      Anonymous                     {None}                        Anonymous                                              True
0a6a00b7-859a-4297-b03f-41... Deleted Items                 Default                       {None}                        Default                                                True
0a6a00b7-859a-4297-b03f-41... Deleted Items                 Anonymous                     {None}                        Anonymous                                              True
0a6a00b7-859a-4297-b03f-41... Drafts                        Default                       {None}                        Default                                                True
```

As you see, the output shows for each user that is set, one time the same folder.

I would like to have only one row per folder with the listing of all User. Something like that:

```
RunspaceId                    FolderName                    User                          AccessRights                  Identity                                            IsValid
----------                    ----------                    ----                          ------------                  --------                                            -------
0a6a00b7-859a-4297-b03f-41... Top of Information Store      Default, Anonymous            {None}                        Default                                                True
0a6a00b7-859a-4297-b03f-41... Calendar                      Default, Anonymous            {AvailabilityOnly}            Default                                                True
```

Comment: Default and Anonymous have different permissions for the folder `Calendar`.

Comment: What is the purpose of this information? You sample output is incorrect for the reason that Ansgar states. You should Default and Anonymous having the same permissions for Calendar where in first output they dont. What you plan on doing with this information could influence how we could make your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? You need to specify how you want to handle combining AccessRights, Identity etc. I made a sample to give you an idea of how to do this, but you need to modify if you want to add extra fields etc.

I don't have access to `Get-MailboxFolder` or `Get-MailboxFolderPermissions`, so the output is what I believe it would look like. I'm not 100% sure about the `AccessRights`-part as I don't know the datatype.

```
$combinedUsers = @{n="Users";e={($_.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty User) -join ', '}}
$combinedAccessRights = @{n="AccessRights";e={($_.Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AccessRights) -join ', '}}

get-mailboxfolder -recurse |
get-mailboxfolderpermissions |
Group-Object FolderName |
Select-Object @{n="FolderName";e={$_.Name}}, $combinedUsers, $combinedAccessRights


FolderName                    Users                         AccessRights
----------                    ----                          ------------
Top of Information Store      Default, Anonymous            {None}, {None}
Calendar                      Default, Anonymous            {AvailabilityOnly}, {None}
```